# Can using System.Timers.Timer in excess damage your application?

Tags: c#, timer, console

A have simple consol application game that currently uses a timer to draw the graphics every time the event is fired. Now that I'm comfortable with how the class is created and used, I would like to control the event time of other game aspects.

My question is,  are there consequences to using too many timers in one application, or does it not matter as long as the events don't over lap?
If so, is there a better class to use to change the iteration speed of multiple items?

I did general research before asking, but am new to programming and might not of looked in the correct place. If the question is to cumbersome to answer here, can you recommend documentation to look at on my own?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is a very cheap object.  Having more than a handful of them, all activating code at unpredictable times and all running on different threads produces a program that is no longer debuggable.  You'll give up on making it work long before the CLR gives up on keeping your program running.  Google "c# game loop" to get ahead.

Comment: Indeed. Game loops are as fundamental to game programming, as pointers and jumps are to programming and Events to any GUI: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

Answer (score 1):

Game Development is not usually done in Console, WinForms or WPF. Game development has it's own approach in .NET (XNA) and approaches in .NET Core (https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/gaming). For certain cases and with very strong limitations it might work out, but it is usually not the best point to start.

Generally the worst danger of any code is "taxing out the CPU".

However unless I am mistaken, System.Timers.Timer might also use multithreading (it is hard to keep those 3-5 timers appart). Wich in turn opens you to the wonderfull world of Race Conditons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software

Normally Consoles are immune to race conditons (purely sequential design) and at least GUI Systems are only slightly succeptible (nature of Event Driven System). But once you add Multithreading, the floodgates are open.

If this is an approach to learnign gamge development, starting with consoles is a bad idea.

If this is about learning C#, starting with a game that requires timers is a poor idea.

Comment: Are you XNA framwork is still available? I cannot find any of it in the .net core or .net standard. The only version I could find says its only compatible with visual studios 10, and windows 8.
I used to console game to help me learn c# when ever a new concept is presented to me in school, I try to integrate it into my game.

Comment: One of the rules I always found out about Microsoft: The may deprecated stuff. They may stop working on stuff. But they rarely (if ever) end up cutting stuff. .NET is still dragging WindowsForms around literal decades after they stopped developing it. The only time they cut it was with .NET -> .NET Core step. Jsut because it is not officially supported, does not mean it will not work. Of course if you plan on learning you should propably be using the .NET Core ways anyway. As far as I can tell, .NET is deprecated/stopped being developed. With all energy going to .NET Core.